# Указание друзей пользователя в базе данных

Tags: mysql, sql

Я пишу учебное приложение. Не могу понять, как мне хранить в базе данных друзей, как в контакте.

У меня есть таблица, которая содержит имя пользователя, его идентификатор, и другую информацию, но не содержит информации о том, кто у него в друзьях.

Хотела у вас спросить, как мне структурировать свою БД, чтобы была возможность узнать друзей определенного пользователя.

У меня есть только один вариант решения, но он, по моему мнению, очень плохой: создать точно такую же таблицу, а потом эти таблицы через вспомогательную связать с помощью foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копия таблицы не нужна. Во "вспомогательной" таблице вы можете создать два внешних ключа к одной и той же таблице.
Итого,

```
create table tesе(id1 int Not null REFERENCES users(id_ user),
id2 int not null REFERENCES users(id_user));
```

Comment: Mysql не разрешает мне это делать, т е я пишу , что-то типо этого
create table tesе(id1 int Not null,FOREIGN KEY (id1) REFERENCES users(id_
user),id2 int not null, FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES users(id_user));
на второй внешний ключ mysql ругается

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало

Comment: Ну и хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще лучше создать таблицу friends, там сделайте поля id|user_id|friend_id|status 
Тут объяснять ничего не нужно в принципе, в поле status если 1, то это подтвержденная заявка, если 0, то ешё ещё не подтвердили заявку

Comment: но тут получится что либо копировать строки нужно, либо у пользователя один друг

Comment: в смысле? циклом бегай и считай друзей юзера где status = 1 и user_id = равен вашему id

Comment: Если

    1 | 2 | 1
    1 | 3 | 1
    1 | 4 | 0

В даннмо случае будет означать, что у пользователя с ID=1 есть два подтвержденных друга с ID=2 и 3. И один друг не подтвержден и ожидает подтверждения.

Comment: Собственно, у @qwas13 это и называется "вспомогательной таблицей". :-) И все мы говорим об одном и том же.

Comment: Иначе никак, еще при больших размерах надобы кешировать...

Answer (score 0):

```
table `friends`
(
...
    `user_id`,
    `friend_id`
)
```